# How to wake an app when screensaver is displayed

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I have an application that gets hidden (but is still running in the background) when the screen saver starts on the 4th Generation Apple TV.

How can I bring the app to the foreground (hide screen saver) when an event (update to an endpoint which I am long polling) happens in my app which is running in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this.  When the screen saver is running, your app can still be the foreground app, but it will be in an inactive state.  This is similar to what happens on iOS when the user locks the screen while using an app.  Like the iOS lock screen, the user might be actively using the system when it's in this state.  For example, you can use Siri without dismissing the screen saver.